# My form always sends the first option

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I have a very simple HTML form. The form is connected to a PHP file so it emails the results to me. But I have a problem with radio buttons. No matter what radio button the user selects, the email always says that the user selected the first radio button.

I've done some research and I think I need to write "echo $gender;" in the PHP file somewhere. I've tried this and Dreamweaver always marks it as a syntax error.

Here is the essential code:

HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female" /> Female<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male" checked /> Male<br>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
$("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        // Prevent spam click and default submit behaviour
        $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
        event.preventDefault();

        // get values from form
        var gender = $("input#gender").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {gender: gender},
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                // Enable button & show success message
                $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", false);
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');

                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry, it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
        })
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});

$("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
});
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php   
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'me@myemailaddress.com'; 
$email_subject = "New message from contact form";
$email_body = "Gender: $gender \n\nPress 'reply' to respond to the sender.";
$headers = "From: me@myemailaddress\n";
return true;            
?>
```

Comment: Well.. you are using jQuery syntax there, not PHP... Please post more code. And why would you need to write $room_type? What does that contain? The gender? I'm confused :p

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant to type "gender" there, not "room_type".

Comment: And how are you submitting this form? By AJAX? This `var gender = $("input#gender").val();` is not PHP - it's JavaScript (jQuery). What does your PHP script looks like?

Comment: So, replace your gender variable with `var gender = $('input[name="gender"]:checked').val()`. In your PHP you can retrieve it by `$_POST['gender'];`

Comment: Sorry, I added the PHP file just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you meant `jQuery` instead of PHP. Also, what you are looking for is:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="female" /> Female<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="male" checked /> Male<br>
</form>

var gender = $("input.gender:checked").val();
```

What I did is change the `id #` to a `class .`. I added a `:checked` to your jQuery selector so it will always get the selected item.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that did it. :D

Answer (score 2):

Both ids are the same, which will cause big problems. Ids should always be unique on the page. It's finding the first because the id is tied to it first.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use php code for this like `$gender = $_REQUEST['gender'];` if you are using jquery to get value of checkbox then you need to get value of checked radio button

For jQuery you can get like this:

```
var gender = jQuery('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code for get the selected gender radio button.

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('input[type=radio][name=gender]').change(function() {
      var c= $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
     alert(c)
     });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="female" /> Female<br>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="male" checked /> Male<br>
    </form>
```